# Alternative to cmp moving from python 2 to 3? Little python experience.

Tags: python

Currently I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\Desktop\project_7-8-2015\8_bands\Program_camera.py", line 47, in <module>
if (cmp(before, after) != 0):
NameError: name 'cmp' is not defined
```

when I run:

```
# CAMERA IMAGE ANALYZE 
camera_directory = "/Users/Dilshad/Dropbox/Camera Uploads"      # Directory of camera uploads
os.chdir(camera_directory)                                              # Change directory to location of photo uploads
path = "."
before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(path)])

print('Waiting for image to be uploaded...\n')
while True:                                                             # Wait a new image in the directory
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
    after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir(path)])
    if (cmp(before, after) != 0):
        break;
print('New file detected.\n')                                           # New image detected
```

I know that cmp was dropped from python 3, and I tried the suggested (a > b) - (a < b) from What's New in Python 3 by substituting in (before > after) - (before < after), but I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Dilshad\Desktop\project_7-8-2015\8_bands\Program_camera -   test.py", line 46, in <module>
if ((before > after) - (before < after) != 0):
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() > dict()
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know if a file was added to (or removed from) the directory, compare the amount of `keys` the `dict` has. 
According to your algorithm, a new key should be added when a new file is found (which also means you'll find less keys than before when a file is deleted).

```
if (len(before.keys()) < len(after.keys())):
        break;
print('New file detected.\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare them with `==`

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2}
a = {'a':1, 'b':2}
b = {'a':1, 'b':2}
print(a == b)
b['a'] = 3
print(a == b)
# reset
b['a'] = 1
print(a == b)
# add a new key-value pair
b['c'] = 3
print(a == b)
```

Which prints

```
True
False
True
False
```